# Getting error using neuralnet function at R

Tags: r, neural-network

I am getting an error, while running the below code:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(datasets.load)

Neural_Net = neuralnet(formula = dist ~ mag , data =  attenu, hidden = C(1,3) )
```

I get the below error:

```
Error in C(1, 3) : object not interpretable as a factor
```

I couldn't solve the problem. Where am I doing wrong?

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `C(1, 3)` uppercase of letter c, should be lowercase, R is case sensitive. Best regards :)

Comment: @Adamm, thanks a lot:)